# Passing Values Back and Forth from Browser to Controller Using JSON

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I found a workaround for errors parsing JSON strings sent from (Firefox) browser using `JSON.parse()` in my controller, but isn't there a better solution?

rails 2.3.12
json (1.6.1)

---

### View --> Controller

---

`views/theme_maps/edit.html.erb`:

(javascript)

```
var labels = ["4", "5"];
document.getElementById("labels").value = JSON.stringify(labels);
```

(html)

```
<% form_for(@theme_map}) do |f| %>  
<input type="hidden" id='labels' name='labels' />  
<%= f.submit 'Update' %>  
<% end %>
```

---

`theme_maps_controller#update`:

(ruby)

```
  labels = params[:labels]     # get it from the hidden field
```

### the problem, and my hack solution, is here:

```
  #   labels.inspect returns: "\"[\\\"4\\\", \\\"5\\\"]\""  
  #   JSON.parse(labels) throws an exception.  
  labels.gsub!('"[', '[')  # remove the quotes  
  labels.gsub!(']"', ']')  # around the brackets.  
  labels.gsub!('\\', '')   # remove the escaped backslash.  
  #   now labels.inspect returns:  "[\"4\", \"5\"]"  

  labels_array = JSON.parse(labels) 
  #   now it's happy.
```

---

### Controller --> View

---

Just to round things out, and because it took me ages to figure this out:

`theme_maps_controller#edit`:
(ruby)

```
  label_list = ["1", "2","3"]
  @json_labels = label_list.to_json
```

---

`views/theme_maps/edit.html.erb`:

(javascript)

```
  var exist_labels = <%= @json_labels %>;
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what your issue is.  You should never have to "fix" properly-done JSON either at the server or the client.

Comment: I edited the question to highlight the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using `JSON.stringify()`. What is needed is `.toSource()`.

```
var labels = ["4", "5"];
// document.getElementById("labels").value = JSON.stringify(labels);
document.getElementById("labels").value = labels.toSource();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the goal is to receive, on the server, something like this:

```
params[:labels]     # ["1", "4", "5"]
```

Honestly, you should pick one mime-type here and stick with it. If you're willing to post with actual JSON data (say, via an AJAX call), then your submitted data will work with no server-side changes and would look like this:

```
{labels: ["1", "4", "5"]}
```

If you're submitting form data, however, your request should look like this:

```
labels=1&labels=4&labels=5
```

Again, that would be interpreted correctly with no server-side changes.

TLDR: Don't try to encode and decode JSON strings stuffed into form fields, it doesn't make much sense on the client or the server.

Comment: I see now that I am mixing mime-types. Thanks for making that clear.